# Take the difference between two columns

Tags: r, subset

I have two data: list contains 271 values and listfull contains 355 values (271 of them are the same as in list). What I want is to print out the 84 different values in these two files. When I write the codes to print the "same" values, they work but not for the "different case". I tried to figure out why but could not. Can you please help me out of this. Thanks

```
list<-read.table("C:\\Data\\list.txt", header=T)
listfull<-read.table("C:\\Data\\listfull.txt", header=T)



for (i in 1:271)
{
  for (j in 1:355)
  {
    if(list$Cow_ID[i]==listfull$Cow_ID[j])
    bo<-data.frame(listfull[j,])

   }
    write.table(bo,"C:\\Data\\store.txt",row.names = FALSE, dec = ".", na = "NA", sep = " ", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE)
}
```

//These above codes work!

//But not the following:

```
for (i in 1:355)
{
for (j in 1:271)
{
if(listfull$Cow_ID[i]!=listfull$Cow_ID[j])
  bo<-data.frame(listfull[i,])

  }

  write.table(bo,"C:\\Data\\store.txt",row.names = FALSE, dec = ".", na = "NA", sep = " ", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE)
}
```

Here how list and listfull look like:

```
Lisfull List
Cow_ID  Cow_ID
26       26
32       32
35       35
219      219
302      302
308      308
383 
400 
441 
445 
446 
453 
462
```

Comment: Can you please give us some sample data so that we can help you better?

Comment: @Yoda: I've added the example of list and listfull. They are simply two list of animal ID, and I want to take the ones that is only exsiting in listfull, but not in list!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `setdiff(listfull$Cow_ID, list$Cow_ID)`.

Eg with some reproducible example:

```
l1=c(26, 32, 35, 219, 302, 308, 383, 400, 441)
l2=c(26, 32, 35, 219, 302, 308)
setdiff(l1, l2)
> [1] 383 400 441
```

You could also use `%in%` or `match` but it's less straithforward I guess.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: With the comment of Richard. It works for this solution as well. I am happy to keep these options for future works. Thanks all!

Comment: Thanks to @Richard !

Answer (score 1):

Would be better if you gave us some data to work with (will update this answer when you do), but to get the difference, why not try:

`listfull$Cow_ID[!listfull$Cow_ID %in% list$Cow_ID]`

Added benefit is you don't need a for loop anymore.

**UPDATE**

Seen your data. The above code should work fine.

Comment: I never imagined this solution, as I have always thought of "a for loop". Much more to learn!Thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to help! Plus for your first line (i.e. to get those **in** the full list), just remove the exclamation mark, viz:
`listfull$Cow_ID[listfull$Cow_ID %in% list$Cow_ID]` Also look into `setdiff` as answered by @Vincent too...